# Entire function bounded by a polynomial is a polynomial with a less or equal degree- complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials, entire-functions

There is an entire function $f$, that is bounded by polynomial $p(z)$ with degree $n$, meaning that

$|f(z)|≤|p(z)|$ for every $z\in\mathbb C$.

Show that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ (less or equal to $n$).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to suppose "wrong" that f is in a degree n+1.

Comment: meaning f=(z-z0)(z-z1)....(z-zn)(z-z(n+1))

Comment: And g=(z-z0)(z-z1)....(z-zn). But we now that f is smaller than g.  And than I got stuck